# Feature in Angular4 with both lazy and eager loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Has anyone created a feature for an Angular4 app that contains one eager and one lazy loaded module? Let say we have a Fruits feature in a big application.

The **fruits.module** would be lazy-loaded and contain all the pages for the Fruits feature. It loads when navigated to. It might use **fruits.components.module** se below.

The **fruits.components.module** (like a sharedmodule) would be eager loaded and contain all the shared components that other modules might want to have. Ex: It could be fruit list widget(usage in **plants.module**) or a fruitLabel with navigation possibilities to fruits.module.

Is this a bad Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just import the "fruits.components.module" module in main module which attains the eagerly loading. 
Coming to lazy loading use the loadChildren property in routing to attain it.

Comment: Everything is actually working. Just wanted feedback if its a good thing to do.

Comment: Sorry haven't seen that, lets wait for a expert then.